# Exporting more than 12 billion Data Extension records

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export

What's the best practice/solution to export more than 12 billion records from SendLog DE in the marketing cloud. As per MC help document suggestion, it should be no more than 30 Million records per file/DE. Based on that I have to create 400's DE :).

What are other available solutions to export all 12 billion records in TXT format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend exporting that much data.

What I've done in the past is to write queries that pull SendLog data into archive Data Extensions as overwrites.  The trick is to get the archival queries to run in under 30 minutes.

For example you may create archive SendLog Data Extensions by year and month. Once all of them are populated you can pause all sends and triggered send definitions, run one last archival query and clear the SendLog  Data Extension.

Once you've cleared the Send Log Data Extension, immediately set an appropriate retention on it in Contact Builder.

Of course if you don't care about data older than 24 months (or whatever), don't create archive Data Extensions and queries for those ranges.

You can also set retention on your archival Data Extensions, so they disappear after a certain period of time.

Comment: Thanks Adam. We already have a backup or archival SendLog DE, actually, I was trying to export data from Archival DE and the reason is business is looking to import those data into their external DB.